# Problem with understanding keys bindings

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, escape-characters

I have a settings and a zsh session

```
~ bindkey | grep help    
"^[H" run-help
"^[h" run-help
```

Why when i press "Control + [ + h" word under cursor removes and nothing happens, but if i press "Alt + h" man page opens correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[` actually means Escape character. Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

In your case it seems your ALT key works as a synonym for Escape key:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_key

Comment: No. Other bindkeys with Ctrl works normal.

Comment: What you mean "with Ctrl"? Can you give an example?

Comment: "^W" backward-kill-word. Ctrl + W removes previous word.

Comment: Man, single `^` means Ctrl and `^W` works with `Ctrl + W`, but `^[` is a special character on its own so it is not `Ctrl + [`.

Comment: @alpert `^[` in fact *does* mean `Ctrl + [`, you can just not combine it with other characters by pressing them at the same time.

Answer (score 9):

Try pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> immediately followed by <kbd>h</kbd>.

Terminals do not send key presses directly to the shell (as in <kbd>Control</kbd> was pressed/released). Instead the terminal sends character sequences depending on keys pressed. The keys in a sequence are to be pressed - well - in sequence, not all at once. The big exception to this are the <kbd>Control</kbd>-keys and the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-keys which are pressed at the same time with other keys to create a specific sequence.

As you already know/noticed `^` is used as symbol for the <kbd>Control</kbd>-key, but it only has this meaning in conjunction with the following character. `^A` means <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the key sequence is the same for upper and lower case characters in combination with <kbd>Control</kbd> (that is also the reason why terminals often use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SOMEKEY</kbd> for their own, not shell-related shortcuts).

`^[` literally means <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. It is also sent by the <kbd>Escape</kbd>. So `^[a` means <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> (lower case!). Additionally, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key also sends the `^[` sequence followed by the key it was pressed with. So <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> also sends `^[a`. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> sends `^[A`.

---

So for your example you can press either of these ('+' means "at the same time", ',' means "in sequence"):

- for `^[h`

  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>
  - <kbd>Escape</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd>
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd>
- for `^[H`

  - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>
  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>
  - <kbd>Escape</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

---

Special keys like <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>KP_Enter</kbd> also send key sequences. These often depend on the terminal emulator. You can use the `quoted-insert` or `vi-quoted-insert` widgets to show the key sequence. By default they is bound to `^V` in their respective modes. So pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by the key combination in question will show the sequence you can use for `bindkey`. For `termite` on my machine I get:

- <kbd>PgUp</kbd>: `^[[5~`, which is also <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>,<kbd>[</kbd>,<kbd>5</kbd>,<kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd>,<kbd>[</kbd>,<kbd>5</kbd>,<kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>,<kbd>5</kbd>,<kbd>~</kbd>
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd>: `^?`, which is also <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>
- <kbd>Return</kbd>: `^M`, which is also <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>
- <kbd>KP_Enter</kbd>: `^[OM`, which is also <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>

---

In theory the key sequences can be arbitrarily long and complicated. For example with:

```
bindkey '^[xfooba^r' run-help
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>f</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> will run the `run-help` widget.

There is a bit of a limit as `zsh` only waits a certain time for another character, before it accepts a multi-character sequence. This timeout can be configured in the `KEYTIMEOUT` parameter in hundredths of seconds. The default is `40`, so 0.4 seconds.

Comment: what does `^[^[[D` mean? It was in `bindkey '^[^[[D' emacs-backward-word`.

Comment: @blueray This translates to the sequence `Control`+`[`, `Control`+`[`, `[`, `D`, which is the same as `Esc`, `Esc`, `[`, `D`. Depending on the terminal there are some other key combinations that send the same sequence. `Esc`, `[`, `D` is the sequence (usually?) sent by the `Left` key. So pressing `Esc`, `Left` should have the same effect. In some terminal emulators you can even press `Alt`+`Left` to achieve the same effect (for me this works with `urxvt` but not with `xterm` or `termite`, which send `^[[1;3D` instead).